# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. in shopify polaris

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, polaris

I am using Shopify Polaris to build an application and have a common post data method for fetching data but when I do this I am getting the following error.please help me to do this

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app Seefor tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

```
import Path from './Path';
import StatusValidation from './Validation';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import React, {useCallback, useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export function PostBeforeLogin(pathValue, type, userData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(Path(pathValue) + type, {
            method:'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(userData),
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        })
        .then((response) => StatusValidation(response))
        .then((responseJson) => {
            resolve(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}

export function PostData(pathValue, type, userData, formData = false) {
    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['acToken']);
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(Path(pathValue) + type, {
            method:'POST',
            body: formData ? userData :JSON.stringify(userData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': formData ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookies.acToken
            },
        })
        .then((response) => StatusValidation(response) )
        .then((responseJson) => {
            resolve(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: well can you confirm all those above 3 things are true and then where are you rendering `<PostData />`?

Comment: Hey i dont use that as a component since i used that as a common function  PostData("pathvalue","apiiURL").then(result =>{
      console.log(result);
    }) like this

Comment: that's your problem then. the docs say: `Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.`

Comment: then is there any other way to call my token inside the headers without using hooks

Comment: try my answer, should work

Comment: I hope it will work I was thought about this way also but since I don't want to pass token value from all the components. I want to have this value in only one place.

Comment: you shouldn't need to pass through loads of components if you put `useCookie` in the same one was the function invoking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
export function PostData(pathValue, type, userData, formData = false, cookies) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(Path(pathValue) + type, {
            method:'POST',
            body: formData ? userData :JSON.stringify(userData),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': formData ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + cookies.acToken
            },
        })
        .then((response) => StatusValidation(response) )
        .then((responseJson) => {
            resolve(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

pass `cookies` in as an argument to this function and remove `useCookies`. then move this code: `const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['acToken']);` to where you call `PostData()` and it should work